# Where is “responsive.css” in wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design

Posted this earlier, forgot to provide a link:
http://amesmakerspace.thenittygritty.org/

Trying to build the above site, and trying to change how it responds to changing the width of a browser window. In chrome I right-click and choose "inspect element" and for the dive "header-right" it shows that the width is changing based on "responsive.css?ver=3.9.2*". I have no idea what that is. When I select the style sheet, it shows "@media screen and (max-width:1240px)" at the top. I am able to change things, but I have no idea where to find the responsive.css sheet in wordpress. Anyone know where it is so I can edit it?? It is absolutely nowhere in the "editor" menu, I checked everywhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

responsive.css is placed insider youthemefolder/css/responsive.css.

As you can see the Url http://amesmakerspace.thenittygritty.org/wp-content/themes/Cinematix/css/responsive.css

you can't access this file from wp-admin editor.

you can access using FTP or C-panel

you need c-panel credential where you can go and change.

Need any other help you can tell me anytime

Comment: thanks a lot.
they also provided me the same answer here for anyone who has the same question:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/where-is-responsivecss?replies=5

Comment: ... and as it is discussed in the link above, you can add "custom css manager" as a plugin and copy-paste the responsive.css file, and edit it in worpress itself then. Would suck to have to use ftp or cpanel...